# Delay loading for specific elements with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, delay, lazy-loading

I'm a JS/JQ noob trying to delay the loading of certain elements until the rest of the page has loaded.

Specifically, there are several lists per page containing social media iframes/remote scripts as list items and whose urls are generated with php.

My best guess would be something like this (inline):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.post-meta-bottom').append('                               
                                <li class="like-button">
                                    <iframe class="fblikebutton" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode($this_permalink); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show-faces=false&amp;width=80&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:30px"></iframe>
                                </li><!--like-button-->

                                <li class="tweet-button">
                                    <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php echo $this_permalink; ?>" data-text="<?php echo $this_title; ?>" data-count="horizontal" data-via="" data-related="">Tweet</a>
                                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
                                </li><!--tweet-button-->

                                <li class="reddit-button">
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        reddit_url = "<?php echo urlencode($this_permalink); ?>";
                                        reddit_title = "<?php echo $this_title; ?>";
                                        reddit_target= "gaming";
                                    </script>

                                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.reddit.com/static/button/button1.js"></script>
                                </li><!--reddit-button-->
                            ')
});
```

...Which doesn't work and I'm sure isn't the best way to do it anyhow.

Anyone care to help? Thanks!

Comment: no that won't work because js is client side.  All of those php elements are evaluated on the server side.  Just place those elements in the .php file and it will be loaded by the time the client views the page.  For delaying php loads, you should ask the php guys.

Comment: Can you post the entire page source?

Comment: @Joseph

I intend to put this inline so the PHP would have already done this thing before the JS.

Comment: @ryan
I updated the code in my question to the actual code I'm trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use load() (since you say that this is inline, i imagine that you are echoing the value from php before sending the javascript - everything is done server side):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.post-meta-bottom').load(function(){
                           $(this).append('<ul>
                                     <li><?php echo facebook_iframe_stuff; ?></li>
                                     <li><?php echo reddit_javascript_stuff; ?></li>
                                     <li><?php echo dynamic_twitter_link; ?></li>
                                     <li><?php echo etc_etc; ?></li>
                                   </ul>');
     });
});
```

Taken from documentation:

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

Comment: Thanks Nicola That looks like what I'm looking for, however it doesn't work!

Comment: I've updated the code in my question to be what I'm actually trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a jQuery expert, but why not use `.delay(time)`?